# How to get duration of uploaded audio/video file

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, upload, price

How to calculate the total duration of audio/video with a price per second?

For Example, if uploaded audio/video is 2 minutes and price per minute is $1, the total price is going to be:

```
Total = duration * price per minute/second
```

I'm using the Contact Form 7 plugin. Is it possible to play around with codes?